# How do I compute this triple summation?

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1} i + j + k$$

The question is looking for a $\Theta(g(n))$ function to represent this summation, but I am uncertain how to go about computing triple summations.

P.S. This is not homework. It was actually an exam question for a class that I missed today.

Comment: If it is a $\Theta$ question, the answer is immediate: Sum once we get a square plus lower terms, sum twice we get a cube plus lower terms, sum $3$ times $\dots$. As for explicit answer, either use the geometry, or do the sums one at a time, using "known" formulas for $\sum_1^{m} k$, $\sum_1^m k^2$ and $\sum_1^m k^3$. That is quite tedious.

Comment: See my comment below. It looks like the answer is $\boxed{n(n-1)^2(n-2)/4}$. I checked and this matches for $n=1,2,3$. The sums are mostly empty until you reach $n=3$, when it becomes simply a single sum $2+1+0=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}( i + j + k) &=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}i+
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}j+
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}k \\ &=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} ij+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} j^2+
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \frac{j(j-1)}{2} \\ &=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{i^2(i-1)}{2}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \frac{i(i-1)(2i-1)}{6}+
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \frac{i(i-1)(i-2)}{6} \\ &=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{i^2(i-1)}{2}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  \frac{i(i-1)(3i-3)}{6}
=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i(i-1)(2i-1)}{2}.
\end{align}
Can you continue after this?

Answer (score 1):

Split it into this:

$$
S = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1} i + j + k = 
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( i + \left(\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \left(j + \sum_{k=0}^{j-1} k\right) \right)  \right)
$$
The innermost sum is $j(j-1)/2$; add $j$ to that to get $j(j+1)/2$. Factor out the $1/2$ and get
$$
S = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( i + \left(\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} j^2 + j \right)  \right)
$$
Now apply the summation rule for $j^2$ and for $j$ in the same way, and then the summation rules for $i^3, i^2,$ and $i$, and you'll get an answer.

Comment: You beat me to it. +1 for you. I got $\boxed{n(n-1)^2(n-2)/4}$ in the end, but I haven't checked my work. I'll try plugging in a few test values and computing by hand.

Comment: In the summand, each of $i,j,k$ must be triple-summed (see solution by Yiorgos). However, this is not the case in the rightmost expression of the first equation line in the solution above.

Comment: You're correct. But the error doesn't affect the big-theta class of the answer, so I'm not going to take the time to fix it, esp since Yiorgos already did it rather nicely.

Answer (score 1):

***(New Solution)***

This solution is much neater than the earlier solution (see below). 
$$\begin{align}
S
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}i+j+k=\color{lightgrey}{\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}i+j+k}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{s=n-i\\\;=r+1}^{n-1}\sum_{t=n-j\\\;=s+1}^{n-1}3(n-1)-(r+s+t)
&&\scriptsize{r=n-1-i\\s=n-1-j\\ t=n-1-k}\\
&=\sum_{t=2}^{n-1}\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}3(n-1)-(t+s+r)
&&\scriptsize 0\le r<s<t\le n-1\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}3(n-1)-(i+j+k)\tag{2}\\
&=\frac 32(n-1)\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{j=2}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1
&&\frac {(1)+(2)}2\\
&=\frac 32(n-1)\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{j=2}^{n-1}\binom j1\\
&=\frac 32(n-1)\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\binom i2\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 32(n-1)\binom n3}\\
&=\color{red}{\frac {n(n-1)^2(n-2)}4}\\
&=\color{red}{\binom {n-1}2\binom n2}
\end{align}$$

---

***(Earlier solution below)***

This solution arrives at the solution in the form of the product of two sums of integers.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}(i+j+k)
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}(i+j+k)\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sum_{s=1}^{j}(i+2j-s)
&&(s=j-k)\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{s=1}^{i-1}\sum_{j=s}^{i-1}(i+2j-s)
&&(1\le s\le j\le i-1)\\
&\color{lightgrey}{=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{s=1}^{i-1}(i-s)(i-s)+2\cdot \frac {i-s}2(s+\overline{i-1})}
&&\color{lightgrey}{\text{(number of steps=$i-s$)}}\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{s=1}^{i-1}(i-s)(i+\overline{i-1})\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{r=1}^{i-1}r(i+\overline{i-1})
&&(r=i-s)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-2}r\sum_{i=r+1}^{n-1}(i+\overline{i-1})
&&(1\le r<i\le n-1)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-2}r\sum_{i=r+1}^{n-1}i+\sum_{r=1}^{n-2}r\sum_{i=r+1}^{n-1}(i-1)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-2}r\sum_{i=r+1}^{n-1}i+\sum_{r=1}^{n-2}r\sum_{i=r}^{n-2}i\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-2}r\sum_{i=r+1}^{n-1}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i\sum_{r=1}^{i}r
&&(1\leq r\le i\le n-2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i\sum_{r=i+1}^{n-1}r+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i\sum_{r=1}^{i}r\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i\left(\sum_{r=1}^i r+\sum_{r=i+1}^{n-1}r\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}r\\
&=\color{red}{\binom {n-1}2\binom n2}\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 14n(n-1)^2(n-2)}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

This represents three loops nested together. And a simple loop has order $\Theta(n)$. And also in general $\Theta(f\circ g)=\Theta(f)\Theta(g)$. And if you have a loop that depends *arithmetically* on an outer loop, then the order of the inner loop is the same as the outer loop. Thus in your case you have that the time complexity is $\Theta(n^3)$.

Comment: This has a few problems - while the intention is good, it's lacking a lot of precision as to, for instance, what a 'simple loop' is.  And it's _not_ true that the complexity of the result is $\Theta(n^3)$; see other answers.

Comment: The complexity for the loops all together is. I did misread the problem though: the complexity for the *summation* is $\Theta(n^4)$.